# Display CSV data on a Visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, csv

I want to read in a CSV file and display the data as a table in a VF page. So for example my file might look like this:

```
Name, category, description, Priority, Type, Status, Number, 
Issue11, Decision Required, Bad data, High, System, txt,100,
Issue15, Decision Required, Some data, Low, System, tyxt,200,
Issue13, Decision Required, Some data, Low, System, texta,300,
```

After the text is displayed the user will be able to insert into an object but initially i just want to display the file values (7 columns, 3 data rows) before any object associations are made.  The problem i am having is how do i reference the separate column names in the VF page so each value display in a column.
If i were association with an object (eg Account) i could use for example the code:
`<apex:column value="{!val.name}" />` to display the 1st column
But how do i reference the value when the data is just from the file itself.
I've tried list of list, a list of maps but i can't get this to work.

The code i am using is of this form:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!alist}" var="l">
    <apex:dataList value="{!l}" var="c">
          {!c}
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:repeat>
```

So an example i have tried is this

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="myMap">
   <apex:pageblocktable value="{!myMap}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.name}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.category}" />
   </apex:pageblocktable>         
</apex:repeat>
```

This does not work though. What does the variable c have to be so i can reference the distinct values?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: THe code did not come through so i'll try again The code i am using is of this form:
<apex:repeat value="{!alist}" var="l">
    <apex:dataList value="{!l}" var="c">
          {!c}
    </apex:dataList>
</apex:repeat>

So an example i have tried is this
<apex:repeat value="{!myList}" var="myMap">
   <apex:pageblocktable value="{!myMap}" var="c">
        <apex:column value="{!c.name}" />
        <apex:column value="{!c.category}" />
   </apex:pageblocktable>         
</apex:repeat>

Comment: Apologies for the lack of fromatting, i pasted formatted but the formatting does not come through.

Comment: Can you please post your back-end code where the lists/maps are defined and populated?

Answer (score 1):

1. Use a method to parse the CSV like listed here:

http://developer.financialforce.com/customizations/importing-large-csv-files-via-batch-apex/

2. Parse the first row into a String[] for the headers
3. Parse the remaining rows into a Map with the key being the row number
4. On your page something like this

[image]

Just something quick off the top of my head.

Comment: Eric
I need each of the file values to appear separately not as one string. I need to be able to refer to each value individually.

Comment: Which it what I am doing

Comment: I worked it out, my Vf code just had to have the pageblock & repeat statements swapped around so the repeat is inside the pageblock, then readjusted the variables and it works.